# Count all when indicator is Y

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have two tables.

Table: State/County list of all states, small example below.

```
State  Countyid CountyName
 KY     101      Jefferson
 KY     102      Clark
 KY     103      Henderson
 IN     501      Albany
 ON     601      Franklin
```

second table is a resource table

```
PK_Rescid    state  Nationwide
  64892        KY      Y
  64857        OH      N
  58745        OH      N
```

I would like to count the number of resources in a state. Which would also mean, when the Nationwide indicator is = 'Y' then that count should apply to all states.

Not sure how one would accomplish this. Counting resources to state is easy enough but adding the additional criteria complicates the task.

Comment: Please show us your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` the `DISTINCT` states (per county) to the resources and then `GROUP BY` each state and `COUNT` the number of resources.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE state_counties ( State, Countyid, CountyName ) AS
SELECT 'KY', 101, 'Jefferson' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KY', 102, 'Clark' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'KY', 103, 'Henderson' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'IN', 501, 'Albany' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ON', 601, 'Franklin' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE state_resources (PK_Rescid, state, Nationwide ) AS
SELECT 64892, 'KY', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 64857, 'ON', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 58745, 'ON', 'N' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT s.state,
       COUNT(r.pk_rescid)
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT state FROM state_counties ) s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       state_resources r
       ON ( r.nationwide = 'Y' OR s.state = r.state )
GROUP BY s.state;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> STATE | COUNT(R.PK_RESCID)
> :---- | -----------------:
> ON    |                  3
> IN    |                  1
> KY    |                  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9cb162fe53d98b3d585b365a8df3ae1)*

Comment: The same, great. I believe this is correct. Will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that `pk_rescid` is the primary key of the resource table, you can left join the resource table on either matching states or when it is a nationwide resource and count the `pk_rescid` per state.

```
SELECT s.state,
       count(r.pk_rescid)
       FROM state s
            LEFT JOIN resource r
                      ON r.state = s.state
                         OR r.nationwide = 'Y'
       GROUP BY s.state;
```